# Image on RecyclerView always change when scrolling using RestAPI Android C#

Tags: c#, android, rest, xamarin, android-recyclerview

I'm using RestAPI to get image location then attach it on adapter and use Recyclerview to show the data. The image is stored on server not on phone. Recyclerview works well but the image always change, and when i try to scroll quickly to the end of the data, it will be force close and pop up like this

"Java.Lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 2380812 byte allocation with 976640 free bytes and 953KB until OOM".

[Here](https://youtu.be/aPKOqPDZ9YE) is the video on youtube how my app works.

Here is my code, this is my adapter CrewMemberRecyclerViewAdapter.cs :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Android.Graphics;
using Android.Support.V7.Widget;
using Android.Views;
using Ardiles_App.Resources;
using System.Net;

namespace my_APP
{
    public class CrewMemberRecyclerViewAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter
    {
        //Create an Event so that our our clients can act when a user clicks
        //on each individual item.
        public event EventHandler<int> ItemClick;

        private List<CrewMember> _crewMembers;
        private readonly ImageManager _imageManager;

        public CrewMemberRecyclerViewAdapter(List<CrewMember> crewMembers, Android.Content.Res.Resources resources)
        {
            _crewMembers = crewMembers;
            _imageManager = new ImageManager(resources);
        }

        //Must override, just like regular Adapters
        public override int ItemCount
        {
            get
            {
                return _crewMembers.Count;
            }
        }

        //Must override, this inflates our Layout and instantiates and assigns
        //it to the ViewHolder.
        public override RecyclerView.ViewHolder OnCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
        {
            //Inflate our CrewMemberItem Layout
            View itemView = LayoutInflater.From(parent.Context).Inflate(Resource.Layout.DetailItem, parent, false);

            //Create our ViewHolder to cache the layout view references and register
            //the OnClick event.
            var viewHolder = new CrewMemberItemViewHolder(itemView, OnClick);

            return viewHolder;
        }

        //Must override, this is the important one.  This method is used to
        //bind our current data to your view holder.  Think of this as the equivalent
        //of GetView for regular Adapters.
        public override async void OnBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position)
        {
            var viewHolder = holder as CrewMemberItemViewHolder;

            var currentCrewMember = _crewMembers[position];

            //Bind our data from our data source to our View References
            viewHolder.CrewMemberName.Text = currentCrewMember.nama;
            viewHolder.RankAndPosting.Text = String.Format("{0}\n{1}", "Rp." + currentCrewMember.harga, currentCrewMember.bahan);

            //INI FOTO SEPATU
            string linkGambar = "http://my.server.com/example/images/" + currentCrewMember.fotou;
            Bitmap _bimage;
            // _bimage = GetImageBitmapFromUrl(linkGambar);

            var webClient = new WebClient();
            var imageBytes = await webClient.DownloadDataTaskAsync(new Uri(linkGambar));
            _bimage = BitmapFactory.DecodeByteArray(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);

            BitmapFactory.Options option = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            option.InBitmap = _bimage;
            Bitmap _bfinal;
            _bfinal = getRoundedShape(_bimage, 150, 150);
            //var photoBitmap = await _imageManager.GetScaledDownBitmapFromResourceAsync(currentCrewMember.PhotoResourceId, 120, 120);
            viewHolder.CrewMemberPhoto.SetImageBitmap(_bfinal);
        }

        //This will fire any event handlers that are registered with our ItemClick
        //event.
        private void OnClick(int position)
        {
            if (ItemClick != null)
            {
                ItemClick(this, position);
            }
        }

        //Since this example uses a lot of Bitmaps, we want to do some house cleaning
        //and make them available for garbage collecting as soon as possible.
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            base.Dispose(disposing);

            if (_imageManager != null)
            {
                _imageManager.Dispose();
            }

        }
        public Bitmap getRoundedShape(Bitmap scaleBitmapImage, int width, int height)
        {
            int targetWidth = width;
            int targetHeight = height;
            Bitmap targetBitmap = Bitmap.CreateBitmap(targetWidth,
                targetHeight, Bitmap.Config.Argb8888);

            Canvas canvas = new Canvas(targetBitmap);
            /*
            Android.Graphics.Path path = new Android.Graphics.Path();
            path.AddCircle(((float)targetWidth - 1) / 2,
                ((float)targetHeight - 1) / 2,
                (Math.Min(((float)targetWidth),
                    ((float)targetHeight)) / 2),
                Android.Graphics.Path.Direction.Ccw);*/

            // canvas.ClipPath(path);
            Bitmap sourceBitmap = scaleBitmapImage;
            canvas.DrawBitmap(sourceBitmap,
                new Rect(0, 0, sourceBitmap.Width,
                    sourceBitmap.Height),
                new Rect(0, 0, targetWidth, targetHeight), null);
            return targetBitmap;
        }
    }
}
```

This is CrewManifest.cs

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Android.Content;
using System.Net;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace my_APP
{   
    public class CrewManifest
    {
        public static async Task<List<CrewMember>> GetAllCrewAsync(string kategori)
        {
            string url = "http://my.server.com/example/API/" + kategori;
            List<CrewMember> crewList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<CrewMember>>(await FetchUserAsync(url));
            return crewList;
        }

        private static async Task<string> FetchUserAsync(string url)
        {

            // Create an HTTP web request using the URL:
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
            request.ContentType = "application/json";
            request.Method = "GET";

            // Send the request to the server and wait for the response:
            using (WebResponse response = await request.GetResponseAsync())
            {
                // Get a stream representation of the HTTP web response:
                using (var sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
                {
                    string strContent = sr.ReadToEnd();
                    return strContent;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is my class

```
public class CrewMember
    {
        public string no { get; set; }
        public string nama { get; set; }
        public string uk { get; set; }
        public string fotou { get; set; }
        public string bahan { get; set; }
        public string poin { get; set; }
        public string harga { get; set; }
        public string warna1 { get; set; }
        public string warna2 { get; set; }
        public string warna3 { get; set; }
        public string warna4 { get; set; }
        public string warna5 { get; set; }
    }
```

And this is my JSON data:

```
[{"no":"167","nama":"Elok","uk":"36- 40","fotou":"167-1.jpg","bahan":"","poin":"50","harga":"61800.00","warna1":"Black","warna2":"Burgundy","warna3":"Brown","warna4":"Violet","warna5":null},{"no":"168","nama":"Glow","uk":"37- 40","fotou":"168-1.jpg","bahan":"","poin":"60","harga":"60800.00","warna1":"","warna2":"","warna3":"Brown","warna4":"Violet","warna5":null},{"no":"169","nama":"Hera","uk":"37- 40","fotou":"169-1.jpg","bahan":"","poin":"60","harga":"62800.00","warna1":"","warna2":"","warna3":"Brown","warna4":"Violet","warna5":null},{"no":"170","nama":"Kilau","uk":"32- 35","fotou":"170-1.jpg","bahan":"","poin":"50","harga":"53800.00","warna1":"","warna2":"","warna3":"Brown","warna4":"Violet","warna5":null},{"no":"171","nama":"Sari","uk":"37- 40","fotou":"171-1.jpg","bahan":"","poin":"60","harga":"62800.00","warna1":"","warna2":"","warna3":"Brown","warna4":"Violet","warna5":null},{"no":"172","nama":"Xena","uk":"36- 40","fotou":"172-1.jpg","bahan":"","poin":"50","harga":"54800.00","warna1":"Red","warna2":"","warna3":"Brown","warna4":"Violet","warna5":null}]
```

I'm using Visual Studio 2015 and Xamarin to build this app.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Try to use some image cache library for fetching images ...

E.g https://components.xamarin.com/view/square.picasso

Usage:

```
Picasso.With(context)
       .Load("http://i.imgur.com/DvpvklR.png")
       .Into(imageView);
```

If u need resize image use `.Resize(50, 50)`

```
Picasso.With(context)
       .Load(url)
       .Resize(50, 50)
       .Into(imageView);
```

I think you should read some at Androids Developer page, specially here:[Displaying Bitmaps Efficiently](https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html)

Comment: thanks, the image is not change again, but the second problem still exist. This error message "Java.Lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 2380812 byte allocation with 976640 free bytes and 953KB until OOM".

Comment: Problem solved!
my image size is too large and all of the images will be resized 1 by 1 that make a lot of process.